# Getting Data From Models Connected By An Intermediate Model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following relationships:

```
class BaseModule(models.Model):
    task_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=200)

# packages contain many modules
class ModulePackage(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    individual_modules = models.ManyToManyField(BaseModule, blank=True)
```

```
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    individual_modules = models.ManyToManyField(BaseModule, blank=True)
    module_packages = models.ManyToManyField(ModulePackage, blank=True)
```

When a Student is logged in and goes to their profile page I can print a list of the Student's Packages but cannot figure out how to print a list of BaseModules contained within each Package.

I know I would need to get this data in view. I would need to loop through a Students Packages and obtain the BaseModules that each has. Then pass this data to my template.

Ive spend a long time Googling and looking through SO but cant find anything on this.

Thank you.

Comment: so you have many to many relationship between ModulePackage and Basemodule where is the problem -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: I can get the 'id' of the user's ModulePackage ```request.user.student.module_packages.all().values_list('id', flat=True)``` but I dont know how to go from having that ModulePackage's 'id' to getting a list of its individual_modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this with nested [for loops](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for) in your template.

If you pass an instance of the `Student` model to your template as `student`:

```html
<!-- loop through the student module packages -->
{% for package in student.module_packages.all %}
<div>Package: {{ package.name }}</div>
<ul>
    <!-- loop through each individual module in the package -->
    {% for module in package.individual_modules.all %}
    <li>Task type: {{ module.task_type }}, Topic: {{ module.topic }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You have no idea how much I was over-complicating this and the crazy hacky spaghetti code Ive been throwing together trying to get this working. Trying to extract the packages individual_modules within my views.py. This ```{% for module in package.individual_modules.all %}``` never occurred to me. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Creating a queryset of relevant objects in your views.py makes sense, but doing it this way in the template is probably the simplest approach.